# What is the mount with three tabs and two linkages on these Albinar lenses?

Tags: lens, lens-mount, old-lenses, equipment-identification

I have two Albinar lenses that I want to identify the lens mount for so that I can buy an adapter for my Sony A5000 (E mount) camera. I bought them at a yard sale recently. They are vintage lenses.  Can anyone help me identify the mount on these lenses?

1. Super Albinar MC auto zoom 1:3.5 f=38~70mm 52 diameter No. 803293

   [image: lens 1]
2. Super Albinar Auto 1:5.6 f=100-200 58 diameter No. 94420

   [image: lens 2]

[Additional images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlyvx.jpg) are available.

Comment: If those are the *only* lenses you intend to try, it's a gamble whether getting an adapter would be worthwhile, in terms of image quality. If you plan to try other Pentax lenses, it's definitely worth getting an adapter. Pentax SMC primes are generally very good. If you're interested in zooms, Pentax-A SMC 35-105/3.5 has the nickname "[stack of primes](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/106531/75526)".

Answer (score 1):

Your lenses appear to have [**Pentax K mount**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentax_K-mount). They should work with adapter without any issue. However, image quality is unlikely to be comparable with modern kit lenses.

The Pentax K mount is a bayonet mount with three tabs. There is an aperture control pin that opens and closes the aperture. Opposite that, there is a coupling pin that communicates the aperture setting for metering wide open.

There are multiple variants. When used with adapters, the differences among them is inconsequential. One variant has a "Ricoh pin" that can get stuck on the autofocus screw drive of Pentax bodies. It is *not* an issue with adapters. Also, newer lenses may have electronically controlled aperture and focus that are unusable with adapters.

[image: Ricoh Pin]